# How to create and fill structured array with numba?

Tags: numpy-ndarray, numba

Python 3.9.7, Numba 0.54.0

I wrote this simple code, that works well:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
from collections import namedtuple

Deal = namedtuple('Deal' , ['DateTime', 'Price', 'Quantity'])
dtype_deals = [('DateTime', 'datetime64[s]'), ('Price', 'float64'), ('Quantity', 'uint64')]

# @numba.njit
def my_func():
    deals = []
    deals.append(Deal(np.datetime64('2015-02-27T15:12:12'), 12.48, 10))
    deals.append(Deal(np.datetime64('2015-03-17T15:08:36'), 1.15, 100))
    deals.append(Deal(np.datetime64('2015-04-02T15:14:32'), 11.01, 20))
    return np.array(deals, dtype=dtype_deals)
  
print(str(my_func()))
```

But when I remove the comment before @numba.njit, I get a mistake:

> numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step:
> nopython frontend) No implementation of function
> Function(datetime64[]) found for signature:
>
> > > > (Literalstr)   There are 2 candidate implementations:
>
> - Of which 1 did not match due to:  Overload in function 'make_callable_template..generic': File:
>   numba/core/typing/templates.py: Line 174.    With argument(s):
>   '(unicode_type)':   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific
>   error:
>   TypingError: Casting unicode_type to datetime64[] directly is unsupported.   raised from
>   /home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typing/builtins.py:818
> - Of which 1 did not match due to:  Overload in function 'make_callable_template..generic': File:
>   numba/core/typing/templates.py: Line 174.    With argument(s):
>   '(Literalstr)':   Rejected as the
>   implementation raised a specific error:
>   TypingError: Casting Literalstr to datetime64[] directly is unsupported.   raised from
>   /home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typing/builtins.py:818
>
> During: resolving callee type: class(datetime64[])
> During: typing of call at /home/ivan/eclipse-workspace/MarketAnalysis/Experiment.py (11)
>
> File "Experiment.py", line 11: def my_func():
>
> deals = []
> deals.append(Deal(np.datetime64('2015-02-27T15:12:12'), 12.48, 10))
> ^

Comment: Numba does not support the value in `dtype_deals`. You need to build the Numba type manually. See `numba.types` and `numba.typed`. Moreover, calling `append` is not efficient and will simply not work as written here. One solution is to create the array first with the right size and fill it with direct addressing.

Comment: In a real task, I don't know the size of the array in advance.

Comment: Please, give me example! Numba's documentation is very large, and I can't find the section I need (with an example).

Comment: You can find information about that here: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/types.html#numba.from_dtype . The Numba documentation is quite sparse (typically because such addition are quite recent and still rather experimental). Unfortunately, you likely have to deals with that. There is no much more I can find that you can't. Regarding the array size, you can preallocate a bigger Numpy array and then return a slice if the size is bounded. If it is not, then I am not sure Numba/Numpy is the right tool...